# java:generalized 8 queen to work for any initial state using depth first search

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, n-queens

I try to solve 8-queen problem for any initial state (put the 8 queens on any place in the board) but it gives me a stackoverflow exception.

here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class depth {
public static void main(String[] args) {

   //we create a board
   int[][] board = new int[8][8];
   board [0][0]=1;
   board [1][1]=1;
   board [2][2]=1;
   board [3][3]=1;
   board [4][4]=1;
   board [5][5]=1;
   board [6][6]=1;
   board [7][7]=1;

 IOException e = null;
   eightQueen(8, board, 0, 0, false);
   System.out.println("the solution as pair");
   for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<board.length;j++)
           if(board[i][j]!=0)

           System.out.println("  ("+i+" ,"+j +")");

   System.out.println("the number of node stored in memory "+count1);

   }

   e.printStackTrace();

   }

   public static int count1=0;
   public static void eightQueen(int N, int[][] board, int i, int j, boolean found) {

   long startTime = System.nanoTime();//time start

   if (!found) {
    if (IsValid(board, i, j)) {//check if the position is valid
        board[i][j] = 1;

        System.out.println("[Queen added at (" + i + "," + j + ")");
        count1++;
        PrintBoard(board);

        if (i == N - 1) {//check if its the last queen
            found = true;
            PrintBoard(board);
            double endTime = System.nanoTime();//end the method time

            double duration = (endTime - startTime)*Math.pow(10.0, -9.0);
            System.out.print("total Time"+"= "+duration+"\n");
        }
        //call the next step
        eightQueen(N, board, i + 1, 0, found);
    } else {

        //if the position is not valid & if reach the last row we backtracking
        while (j >= N - 1) {
            int[] a = Backmethod(board, i, j);
            i = a[0];
            j = a[1];

            System.out.println("back at (" + i + "," + j + ")");
            PrintBoard(board);
        }
        //we do the next call
        eightQueen(N, board, i, j + 1, false);
    }
    }

   }

  public static int[] Backmethod(int[][] board, int i, int j) {
  int[] a = new int[2];
  for (int x = i; x >= 0; x--) {
    for (int y = j; y >= 0; y--) {
        //search for the last queen
        if (board[x][y] != 0) {
            //deletes the last queen and returns the position
            board[x][y] = 0;
            a[0] = x;
            a[1] = y;
            return a;
        }
    }
  }
  return a;
}

public static boolean IsValid(int[][] board, int i, int j) {

int x;
//check the queens in column
for (x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
    if (board[i][x] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
//check the queens in row
for (x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
    if (board[x][j] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
//check the queens in the diagonals
if (!SafeDiag(board, i, j)) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}

public static boolean SafeDiag(int[][] board, int i, int j) {

int xx = i;
int yy = j;
while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
    if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    yy++;
    xx++;
}
xx = i;
yy = j;
while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
    if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    yy--;
    xx--;
}
xx = i;
yy = j;
while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
    if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    yy--;
    xx++;
}
xx = i;
yy = j;
while (yy >= 0 && xx >= 0 && xx < board.length && yy < board.length) {
    if (board[xx][yy] != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    yy++;
    xx--;
   }
   return true;
 }
 public static void PrintBoard(int[][] board) {
System.out.print(" ");
for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
    System.out.print(j);
}
System.out.print("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Q");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
   }
  }

  }
```

and the output:

```
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
at depth.eightQueen(depth.java:68)
```

the strange thing is it work for the following initial state:

```
   board [0][0]=1;
   board [1][1]=1;
   board [2][2]=1;
   board [3][3]=1;
   board [4][4]=1;
   board [5][5]=1;
   board [6][6]=1;
   board [7][1]=1;
```

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: half of the stacktrace is missing/

Comment: also, which line is the crash on ?

Comment: `for any initial state` what do you mean ?

Comment: @njzk2 i edited above in my questions.

Comment: @njzk2 crash at line 60,stackoverflow

Comment: from the look of your algorithm, it is rather designed to take an empty board as input, as it immediately attempts to place queens without searching for any present one.

Comment: @njzk2 how to correct this?